# How can I format decimal precision when using a specific locale for the decimal separator?

Tags: python, matplotlib, locale

I need to plot a graph that has 2 decimal places of precision in the y axis. Currently, I am using `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))` to do that.

But now, I need to display the numbers with comma as the decimal separator. When I use `locale` to change the setting for that with `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'pt_BR')` and `plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.use_locale'] = True`, it gets overwritten as I specify the number of decimal places.

This is the code that I used:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter

import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'pt_BR')

plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.use_locale'] = True

x = range(5)
y = range(5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(8, 4))
ax.scatter(x, y)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two issues with your code:

1. `'%.2f'` does not interact with locale settings, it is locale independent. You need to use `locale.format_string()` with it.
2. Use `FuncFormatter` rather than FormatStrFormatter

Something like:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'pt_BR')
plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.use_locale'] = True

x = range(5)
y = range(5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(8, 4))
ax.scatter(x, y)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: locale.format_string('%.1f', x)))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: locale.format_string('%.2f', x)))
plt.show()
```

[image]

[Some examples](https://github.com/enabling-languages/python-i18n/blob/main/notebooks/matplotlib_locale.ipynb) of using locale formatted strings when precision isn't required.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like `FormatStrFormatter()` doesn't take the `set_locale()` into account and uses the default `.`, which overwrites the format. So, you can get the labels, add a zero the end... Updated your code below. Hope this helps...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter

import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'pt_BR')

plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.use_locale'] = True

x = range(5)
y = range(5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))
ax.scatter(x, y)
#ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))

plt.draw()  ## Draw so you can get the ticks and labels
ax.yaxis.set_ticks(ax.get_yticks())  ## Added to ensure no warning
ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels([item.get_text()+'0' for item in ax.get_yticklabels()]) ## Get label, append 0 and write back
plt.show()
```

[image]